# angular to fetch the json service from http

Tags: angularjs, json

I have my js for angular to fetch the json service from http and am using the {{post.title}} on my html to get the data and post to my html.

The data is not showing up on html page - using code pen.

```
var app = angular.module("blogApp", []); 
app.controller("mainCtrl",      function($scope) {
$scope.posts = []; 
let postsUrl ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    getPosts().then(posts =>{
        $scope.posts = posts.slice(3);
        $scope.$apply();
    });

    function getPosts(){
        return fetch(postsUrl).then(res=>res.json());
    }
```

});

Comment: You may want to add the relevant HTML as well. As it stands, I can only guess it's because your code sets `$scope.posts` (which is an array?), not `$scope.post`

Comment: Could we see the JSON for posts, and your view html?

Comment: my html starts with: <div ng-app="blogApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl"></div> and then I have tried to call the post data with <li *ngFor="let post for posts$"> {{post.title}}</li>

Comment: @mediaguru the json is the service https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Comment: As I am using codepen to code, I left off the header tags in my html comment above.

Comment: what is written inside the fetch(postsUrl)?

Comment: @HassaanKhan not sure what you mean. I'm new to angular and not using VS code to get http from json. Instead, the js code above is apparently all I need to pull the json from the url service and post onto my html. I'm sure I'm missing something to get the json data and post into the expression {{post.name}}. Please advise - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen your shared codepen. So Ricky as you are new to angularJS, I would suggest you to read the documentation related to angular 1 from here: [Angular JS - Documentation](https://angularjs.org/)

Now coming to your requirement, you required to call an external API and use the data from the result. For that you have to learn about the `$http` in angularJS : [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Coming to the code, angular supports the dependency injection. The code you have shared is a mystery for me like what `fetch(postsUrl)` function is doing? Where is the declaration?

Cut and short, the implementation should be clear and readable. Here is my refactored one:

```
var app = angular.module("blogApp", []); //here you defined the ng-app module

//you are initializing a controller, you need to inject $http for calling the API 
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

        //Declaration of the posts object
        $scope.posts = [];

        //Onetime initialization of the API Endpoint URL
        let postsUrl ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

        //A method for getting the posts
        function getPosts(){

           //We are calling API endpoint via GET request and waiting for the result which is a promise 
           //todo: Read about the Promises
           //A promise return 2 things either a success or a failure callback, you need to handle both. 
           //The first one is success and the second one is a failure callback
           //So in general the structure is as $http.get(...).then(successCallback, failureCallback)  
            $http.get(postsUrl).then(function(response){

               //In promises you get data in the property data, for a test you can log response like console.log(response)
               var data = response.data;

               $scope.posts = data; //Storing the data in the posts variable

                //Note: you don't need to call the $scope.$apply() because your request is with in the angular digest process. 
                //All the request which are outside the angular scope required a $apply()
            }, function(err){
               //log the err response here or show the notification you want to do
            });
        }

        //The final step is to call that function and it is simple
        getPosts();         

});
```

Coming to the second part to show the data. You have to use the ng-repeat documentation, it is as `ng-repeat="var item in collection track by $index"`. It's documentation is here [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

So you html should be in this structure:

```
<div  ng-repeat="var post in posts track by $index"> 
    {{post.userid}}
    {{post.id}}
    {{post.title}}
    {{post.body}}
</div>
```

Now it is onto you to learn and implement.

Comment: hey Hassaan - WOW - thanks so much for the detailed explanation and answer - I really appreciate it. And your explanation makes total sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @Richy, please accept it as an answer if your query is done thanks